# xcode in App purchase invalid product identifier

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, swift4

I am getting response like below:
Purchase Failed: related decl 'e' for SKErrorCode(_nsError: Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=3 "Invalid product id: au.com.happyheartsandminds.happyhearts.members995" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid product id: au.com.happyheartsandminds.happyhearts.members995})

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to complete the '**Agreements, Tax and Banking**' information **in iTunes connect** first. Without it you will constantly receive this error message.

[Screenshot of iTunes Connect Agreements, Tax and Banking.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPItt.png)

Answer (score -1):

It means that the product Id `au.com.happyheartsandminds.happyhearts.members995` is invalid. Make sure you've configured the product correctly in App Store Connect and the product Id matches.

Here is a quick blog post that explains the common errors of configuring products in more detail: [Configuring In-app Products is Hard](https://www.revenuecat.com/2018/10/11/configuring-in-app-products-is-hard)